# Ugly dark stripe in code chunk of gitbook with highlight: espresso (R bookdown)

Tags: r, bookdown, highlight.js

I use R `bookdown` package to create a gitbook. Recently I noticed an ugly dark stripe under the boxes of code chunks in rendered gitbook (see a printscreen below).  It appeared with `highlight` set to `espresso`. Stripes like this one distract attention when one tries to read the book and looks unattractive.

I can reproduce the result by creating a new bookdown project with RStudio (most probably the same project as the [minimal bookdown example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo)) with the contents of file `_output.yml` replaced with two lines:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  highlight: espresso
```

1. Can anyone else reproduce the problem?
2. How can I rid off the stripe, but still use `highlight: espresso`?

[image]

Comment: what is your version of `pandoc`?

Comment: Pandoc version 2.1.1

Comment: thx. Problem comes from Pandoc >=2. I will enhance my answer soon.

Comment: I added some details to the answer

Comment: @Yihui Xie Thanks a lot! You are extremely generous! (we already know that). I'm embarrassed because you give me so much points.

Comment: @romles No need to feel embarrassed. You have done excellent work. This is just a way to show my appreciation -- you are essentially setting me free from knitr and rmarkdown questions, which is very, very helpful to me. I really need time to focus on other things. If I could, I'd love to give you all my 20k points :)

Comment: @romles you did a really great job.

Comment: @Vilmantas Thanks! I'm interested in better understanding pandoc css because I began to write a package to render Rmd to pdf with CSS https://github.com/RLesur/weasydoc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the use of `pandoc 2.x`.
I reproduced the bug [here](https://rlesur.gitlab.io/bookdown-p2/) and you can see the same `gitbook` with `pandoc 1.19.x` [here](https://rlesur.gitlab.io/bookdown-3.4.3/).
*I wrote a note to explain my [debugging worflow](https://gitlab.com/RLesur/debug-bookdown#a-workflow-for-debugging-side-effects-of-pandoc-v2-on-rmarkdown).*

---

In both versions, `HTML` sources are very close (I voluntary omit `div` and lines ids that [@Yihui Xie dislikes](https://yihui.name/en/2017/11/pandoc-2/)).

```html
<div class="sourceCode">
  <pre class="sourceCode r">
    <code class="sourceCode r">
     <span class="kw">install.packages</span>(<span class="st">&quot;bookdown&quot;</span>)
     <span class="co"># or the development version</span>
     <span class="co"># devtools::install_github(&quot;rstudio/bookdown&quot;)</span>
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

The problem you got is a consequence of a **collision between `gitbook` theme and `espresso` highlighting**.

Firstly, the dark stripe is the "real" background color of `espresso` (see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.9.4.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-Highlighting.html)): the `background-color` of `espresso` highlighting is set to `#2a211c` by `pandoc` (it is hard-coded [here](https://github.com/jgm/skylighting/blob/3dbca4b9f49f52ce571db6b4ba082407304399df/src/Skylighting/Styles.hs#L191)).

The builtin `espresso` highlighting looks like this for `pandoc v2.x` (it is black, like an espresso):

```css
code span.kw {
    color: #43a8ed;
    font-weight: bold;
}
code span.st {
    color: #049b0a;
}
code span.co {
    color: #0066ff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
div.sourceCode {
    color: #bdae9d;
    background-color: #2a211c;
}
div.sourceCode {
    overflow: auto;
}
div.sourceCode {
    margin: 1em 0;
}
pre.sourceCode {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sourceCode">
  <pre class="sourceCode r">
    <code class="sourceCode r">
     <span class="kw">install.packages</span>(<span class="st">&quot;bookdown&quot;</span>)
     <span class="co"># or the development version</span>
     <span class="co"># devtools::install_github(&quot;rstudio/bookdown&quot;)</span>
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

**It is slightly different of `pandoc v1.19.x` where the `background-color` is set for `pre` elements instead of `div.sourceCode`** (it's important).

Secondly, `gitbook` theme overrules **only for `pre` elements** the dark background color of `espresso` with a light grey background (`Hex Gray97`)  and defines a bottom margin (contrary to `pandoc` CSS) [see this file, line #9, column #31963](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/blob/2.6.7/theme/assets/website/style.css):

```
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal pre {
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: normal;
  margin: 0 0 1.275em;
  padding: .85em 1em;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

This bottom margin reveals the background color of the enclosing `div` element:

- in `pandoc 1.19.x`, the enclosing `div` has no `background-color` rule (the background color is applied to `pre` element). So, there's no black stripe.
- in `pandoc 2.x`, the background color is set at the `div` level. There's a black stripe.

---

From your question, I understand that you want the `espresso` highlighting without its "ugly" dark companion. In other words, you want a "white coffee" highlighting.

So, **there are two options**:

- get rid-off the bottom margin
- overrule the background color of `espresso` highlighting

It is a matter of taste.

**First solution** : get rid-off the bottom margin
Save these lines in a file with `.css` extension (e.g. `fix.css`):

```
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal pre {
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

Include this CSS file in your bookdown modifying `_output.yml`:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  highlight: espresso
  css: fix.css
```

**Second solution**: overruling the `espresso` background color with `Hex Gray97`
In this case, you can include these lines in `fix.css`:

```
div.sourceCode {
  background-color: #f7f7f7!important;
}
```

Since the use of the `important` rule is not recommended, you can obtain the same result in a more elegant fashion: **with `pandoc 2.x`, you can customise the highlighting theme**.
[This gist](https://gist.github.com/RLesur/16ae4324444eed736aa001cb41ba4e57) defines a `whitecoffee` theme (it is the `espresso` theme with a `Hex Gray97` background).
Save the `whitecoffee.theme` file at the root level of your project and modify the `_output.yml` file:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  highlight: whitecoffee.theme
```

Comment: I appreciate that you gave me two options to fix the issue. The first one is more appropriate for me as I prefer using `sepia` theme. It is this stripe is a result of recent updates in `gitbook` (as several months ago it was not present using the same code of `bookdown`)?

Comment: I really don't know when and how this bug appeared. CSS is really hard to "debug" and this stripe could be a side-effect of another evolution of the CSS , JS or `pandoc`. Finding when and how this bug appeared requires a lot of hours.

Comment: I've a fun idea to test when this bug appeared. Not yet the time to do it, but I plan to do this

Comment: I also tried to inherit color and it worked: 
`div.sourceCode {
  background-color: inherit !important;
}`
This enables to use gitbook themes including white, sepia, and night